# The import com.android.packageinstaller cannot be resolved

Tags: android

How can I use packageinstaller to install apps programmatically in Android? If I try to use

```
import com.android.packageinstaller;
```

I get "The import com.android.packageinstaller cannot be resolved" error.

When I try directly use PackageManager I cannot use installPackage function:

```
The method installPackage() is undefined for the type PackageManager
```

How could I install 1.app obtained my web server by the other? Is it possible at all?

Comment: I think if the apk is present in the SD card you can call an intent to install the apk file, if that is what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Maybe this question helps you solve your problem:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically

Comment: It's possible through intents; see the linked duplicate. However, it's *not* possible without the user approving it first. That is a **Good Thing**.

Answer (score 0):

This is because it is not part of Android SDK. It is **internal package**. `installPackage()` also not open either.

You can use this packages, methods if you are OEM & compiling against android source code.